# Is it possible to execute draw() only once a frame?

Tags: javascript, physics, processing.js

I'm trying to do a physics simulation in Processing.js, and I only want to execute the draw function once a frame. Is this possible? Or is there another function that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Processing, each `draw` call **is** a (new) frame, and you can regulate either the frame rate with the [`frameRate()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/frameRate_) function, or you can turn off interval-based redraws by calling [`noLoop()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/noLoop_) in your setup function, and then instead using [`redraw()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/redraw_) in a tactical spot to manually trigger a redraw.

Comment: also hi, I'm the developer for processing.js, and didn't copy paste your comment, there's just not a lot of variation in the possible answer here (the only bit you apparently forgot to mention was the need for redraw() when using event based or manual redrawing) O_o

Comment: thanks for the link, but again, I didn't copy paste your answer, we both happened to write very similar answers. But hey, if it makes you feel better, write your comment as an answer instead, and I'll happily delete this one. As long as the OP's question's answered, because as the Pjs dev, that's the only thing I care about for posts with the "processing.js" tag

Comment: ah, I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding, and I'll edit the anwer to include them.